# Creating an Application Based Database

Tags: coldfusion, hsqldb, railo, in-memory-database

I am working on an application where I would like to store all my current user authentications (users that are currently logged in with their login tokens) in a database in memory.  Currently I have an HSQL DB that I do a DROP and CREATE TABLE command onApplicationStart to store the authentications, but I was wondering if their is a way that I could just wipe out the database when the application restarts (currently it is stored until the server restarts).

Is there a way that I could create an in memory database that has limited access from only the application that uses it, and that destroys itself when the application restarts?

Comment: Have you tried dropping from Application.cfc `onApplicationEnd()`: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/AppEvents_04.html#1188612

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this is exactly what you need:

[Networked In-Memory Databases With ColdFusion](http://cfsilence.com/blog/client/index.cfm/2011/1/28/Networked-InMemory-Databases-With-ColdFusion)

[Using An In-Memory Database With ColdFusion (Out Of The Box)](http://cfsilence.com/blog/client/index.cfm/2011/1/27/Using-An-InMemory-Database-With-ColdFusion-Out-Of-The-Box)

Comment: Todd's method works the best with a drop in the onApplicationEnd to clear out the database.  From what I have seen there is no way, unless I just create an Array of structs to do a fully application dependent database.

Comment: Why don't you just wipe the table in onApplicationStart()?  That way you can be sure it's empty when the app starts.

Comment: @ToddSharp These links are not responding.

Answer (score 0):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE <tablename> works in MySQL, maybe there is a similar function?
```

Comment: If I drop the table then it is completely gone, but I was wondering if anyone has any ideas for how I could have the database only stored in memory for as long as the application is alive.  I am guess that my only option is to just drop the table on application end.

Comment: If you are wanting that functionality, it may be easier to simply let the data reside in memory and not even worry about the database.